# Так()же - союз или наречие (см.)?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, союзы, наречия

Уважаемые знатоки, огромная просьба, поделитесь мнением по поводу следующего случая. В ходе интервью тренеру задали вопрос с намеком на то, что он не соответствует занимаемой должности. Его ответ: "Вы справляетесь со своей должностью? Вот и я ТАК()ЖЕ".

Вопрос: *также* или *так же*?

Answer (score 1):

***Вы справляетесь со своей должностью? Вот и я также*** (= тоже справляюсь).

Это союз ТАКЖЕ, а не сочетание ТАК + ЖЕ.

Вариант с раздельным написанием: *Вы хорошо справляетесь со своей должностью? Вот и я справляюсь так же хорошо (как и вы).*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я думаю, что многие знают ответ на этот вопрос, но почему-то никто не хочет высказать свое мнение.

Придется мне привести **дополнительные доказательства**.

1) **Вот сама ситуация** (как это было):

Кононов на вопрос, справляется ли он с работой: «А вы справляетесь? **Ну и я тоже**»

https://www.sports.ru/football/1074125906.html

(Союз ТОЖЕ здесь действительно лучше подходит, чем союз ТАКЖЕ, хотя это союзы-синонимы).

2) **Из словаря:**

**СПРАВИТЬСЯ,** св. 1. обычно с чем. Сделать, выполнить что-л.; суметь сделать, выполнить что-л. **С. с работой.** С. с поручением. С. с задачей. С. с платежами.

Справиться — это **самодостаточное слово**, оно может употребляться без обязательных распространителей. В то же время  можно не только справиться с работой, но и справиться прекрасно, отлично.

Поэтому и существуют **варианты:**

(1) Вы справляетесь с работой? — А вы? — Я справляюсь. — Ну и я тоже (также) справляюсь.

(2) Как Вы справляетесь с работой? — А Вы как справляетесь? —  Я хорошо справляюсь. — Ну и я справляюсь так же хорошо.

Comment: *думаю, что многие знают ответ* — я не знаю и не могу однозначно согласиться с предложенными ответами, чтобы проголосовать. Фраза неудачная (неоднозначная) и всё зависит от интонации, с которой это было сказано. Работа журналиста тоже сложная, как и у тренера. День на день не приходится, и не всё зависит только от тебя. Если подразумевался такой ответ на вопрос "справляетесь?", тогда, наверное, "так же" нужно писать раздельно.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу с Вами согласиться. Бывают случаи, когда оба выражения формально подходят, но тогда учитывается ситуация. Здесь же ситуация предельно ясная. Тренеру не нравится вопрос журналиста (действительно не слишком удачный и корректный). Вы справляетесь со своей работой? Разумеется, справляюсь, иначе бы уже не работал бы здесь. Вот вы справляетесь (если числитесь на своей работе), вот и я ТОЖЕ (ТАКЖЕ) справляюсь. А раздельное написание подразумевает,  как  вы с работой справляетесь (как/так - это местоименные наречия, отнесенные к глаголу). Ничего похожего в вопросе не было.

Comment: Кстати,  тренер же дал ответ: я ТОЖЕ справляюсь. Также - это союз-синоним. И откуда тогда возьмется местоименное наречие ТАК + ЖЕ?

Comment: Соглашусь с Вами. Да я и не особенно настаивал на своих сомнениях.

Answer (score 0):

Полный ответ на утвердительное "да" (которого риторически здесь не дождались) был бы таким: *"Вот и я, **так же как и** вы, справляюсь".*

> http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=710#pp710
>
> *Я знала, **так же** как и она, что рано или поздно наступит день... Ч. Айтматов, Материнское*
>   *поле.*

Имеющийся вариант можно рассматривать как сокращение "*так же как и*" (наречие + частица + союз) до "**так же**" (наречие + частица).